# Foreach loop looping too much

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code and it is going through my results. Problem is it lists the one row in my db table five times. There is the id, name, email, company, and title. How do I just show my result once?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `newsletter`";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        $DATA .= "
            <div id='contentBox'>
            Name: $row[Name]<br />
            Email: $row[Email]<br />
            Company: $row[Company]<br />
            Title: $row[Title]<br />
            <br />
            </div>
        ";
    }
}
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get rid of the foreach loop, you don't need it.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $DATA .= "
            <div id='contentBox'>
            Name: $row[Name]<br />
            Email: $row[Email]<br />
            Company: $row[Company]<br />
            Title: $row[Title]<br />
            <br />
            </div>
        ";
}
```

Remember that you're getting back rows (with multiple columns) from the database.

```
----------------------
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
----------------------
| val1 | val2 | val3 |
----------------------
```

Your `while` loop iterates "down" that table, where each `$row` is a row in the database. Doing a `foreach` on the `$row` will iterate over each column individually.

Comment: Why didn't I see this..lol. Thank you very much for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative that still uses the foreach loop.  The nice thing about this approach is that if you ever add or remove a column you won't need to modify your loop.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `newsletter`";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $DATA .= '<div id="contentBox">';
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        $DATA .= $key . ': ' . $value . '<br />';
    }
    $DATA .= '</div>';
}
```